# sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError Error binding parameter 1

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I try to do the following :

```
def EMA(file):

current_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
five_minutes_ago = current_time - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
sub_within_las_five_min = db.session.query(visits).filter((visits.date > five_minutes_ago),(visits.name == file)).all()
a = len(sub_within_las_five_min)
return a
```

i get the following error :

InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type. [SQL: u'SELECT visits.id AS visits_id, visits.name AS visits_name, visits.date AS visits_date \nFROM visits \nWHERE visits.date > ? AND visits.name = ?'] [parameters: ('2016-02-20 12:06:43.974000', (u'vagrant.txt',))]

I know the problem is caused by the (u'vagrant.txt',) because i tried to put 'vagrant.txt' instead of file and it works  . the file name is generated from this view :

```
  @app.route('/api/test/', methods=['GET'])
  def catalogue1():
  catalogue = db.session.query(Content.name).all()
  for i in range(len(catalogue)):
    j= catalogue[i]
    s = EMA(j)
    return str(s)
```

My models are :

```
   class visits(db.Model):

   __tablename__ = 'visits'

   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   name = db.Column(db.String(20))
   date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)


   class Content(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'Content'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    url = db.Column(db.String(20))
    name = db.Column(db.String(20))
    type = db.Column(db.String(20))
    Hits = db.Column(db.Integer)
    Server_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Server.id'))
    harddrive_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('harddrive.id'))
```

Can someone help !